# Convert UTC time string to local timezone in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, utc

How to convert a string in UTC like '11:00' to local time in the same format. I have used Date function in javascript to convert that but I want a fast and reliable alternative.

Also to get Time zone abbreviation and day of the week in the local timezone.

Comment: momentjs is a common library to use in JS when you have to deal with time and date. Maybe that can help? [http://momentjs.com/timezone/](http://momentjs.com/timezone/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to convert a string in UTC like '11:00' to local time in the same
>   format.

In the following, "local" means values returned by the non-UTC methods, which take into account the host system timezone setting.

One method is to create a Date, set the UTC time to the appropriate time, then read back the local time values, e.g.

```js
var d = new Date();
// Set time to 11:00
d.setUTCHours(11,0,0,0);
// Get "local" date and time
console.log(d.toString());
```

> I have used Date function in javascript to convert that but I
>   want a fast and reliable alternative.

Questions asking for recommendations of books, libraries, tools, etc. are off-topic.

> Also to get Time zone abbreviation

There are various resources to estimate the name of the timezone, however there is no standard for names. Most resolution methods are based on the host timezone offset for various dates, which is not 100% reliable, particularly as there is no agreement on what the name should be.

> and day of the week in the local timezone.

The local day of the week is provided by the *getDay* method, so:

```
var dayNumber = d.getDay(); // 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, etc.
```

If the ECMA-402 Internationalisation interface is supported, you can get week day names in the host default language using:

```js
var d = new Date();
console.log('Today is ' + d.toLocaleString(undefined, {weekday: 'long'}) + '.')
```